PBIRS 2023 data driven subscription is causing error in XML?
An error has occurred.
The input XML does not conform to the schema. XML grammar is described in the API documentation. For XML in reports, refer to Report Definition Language syntax.
This error occurs in PBIRS subscription when I validate query in Data Driven Subscription. What is causing the error and is there a solution to this ?
I've tried to change xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition" to xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2019/01/reportdefinition"

I deleted the DataSource. Recreated and Renamed it. And then it worked.
However it was running previously for other reports.
